# CSS and Javascript: Function to change color effects hover style

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, hover

I have an element where I set a text color and a different text color for the hover state in the CSS. I have some javascript so that when I click the element, it changes the text color of the element. It works fine except that it also effects the hover CSS which I want to remain the same as the pre-clicked hover CSS. Is there anyway to either stop the hover css from being effected or to set the hover CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/77zg8/

CSS:

```
#test {color: blue;}
#test:hover {color:green;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test" onClick="javascript:change()">qwerty</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function change() {document.getElementById("test").style.color="#cc0000";};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of setting the color directly, it would be cleaner (and more effective to use a class).

CSS :

```
#test {color: blue;}
#test.active {color:red;}
#test:hover {color:green;}
```

JavaScript :

```
function change() {
   document.getElementById("test").className='active';
}
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/eV3Wb/)

Comment: Thanks! I might add that if the element already has a class with styles, I would need to give the new class those same styles as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use classes!

```
#test {color: blue;}
#test:hover, #test.foo:hover {color:green;}
#test.foo { color : #cc0000 }
```

Basic JavaScript:

```
function change() {document.getElementById("test").className = "foo"; };
```

Of course you would have to toggle the classes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are running into is the concept of specificity in css. Specificity controls what rules get applied and in what order. Because the javascript updates the style element, it will override the specificity and erase all previous rules regarding the color styling. so instead add a class eg "clicked" to the element. where clicked is your new color

```
.clicked{color:red}

function change() {document.getElementById("test").class += " clicked"};
```

This will do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `!important`  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/77zg8/5/)

```
#test:hover {color:green!important;}
```